# how to get array images from local storage to blade files

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-8

so i stored array of images while created a form, but i store these in local public folder not in database.

//controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        
            if($request->hasFile('files'))
            {
                foreach($request->file('files') as $image)
                {
                    $destinationPath = 'public/uploads/';
                    $filename = $request->input('surf_date').'_'.$request->input('user_id').'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                    $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                }
                
            }
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'post_type' => ['required'],
                'user_id' => ['required','numeric'],
                'post_text' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'files[]' => ['nullable','image','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'],
                'surf_date' => ['required', 'string'],
            );
            
            $validate = Validator::make($data, $rules);
            if ($validate->fails()) {
                // If validation falis redirect back to register.
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
            } else {
                //savePost is service for storing data into database
                $result = $this->posts->savePost($data,$message);
                if($result){  
                    return Redirect::to('admin/post/create')->withSuccess($message);
                }else{
                    return Redirect::to('admin/post/create')->withErrors($message);
                }
            }
        
        
    }
```

while storing it i append user_id and surf_date with it so that it can retreive using this info
now i am showing these data in another view (show.blade)

//controller for show data

```
public function show($id)
    {   
            $post=Post::findOrFail($id);
            $spiner = ($post) ? true : false;
            return view('admin/post/show', compact('post','spiner'));  
    }
```

//show view blade

```
<p class="text-muted text-md"><b>Post Type : </b> {{ __($post->post_type)}} </p>
<p class="text-muted text-md"><b>Post Text : </b> {{ __($post->post_text)}} </p>
<p class="text-muted text-md"><b>User id : </b> {{ __($post->user_id)}}</p>
<p class="text-muted text-md"><b>Surf Start Date : </b> {{ __($post->surf_start_date)}}</p>
```

but i also want to show images in view that stored locally and i don't know how can i achieve that
i am new in laravel please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Since you have not stored the paths to the saved files, it will be a little cumbersome. Ideally you should store the paths to the images (stored) in a database column. You built the names for the files(images) like `$request->input('surf_date').'_'.$request->input('user_id').'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName()`. You know 2 parts `surf_date` and `user_id` . So you will need to retrieve files from `public/uploads/` and then do a preg_match on filenames with a pattern `$post->surf_date . '_' . $post->user_id` because you don't know the original filenames

Answer (score 1):

Hi 
 I think the best idea is using the database to store the data of the images but if you want to do not use the database you can use the "glob" function in php 
For example you can save the images with this pattern

```
$userId . "_" . $date . $originalFileName
```

Now it you want to get one specific user image in the specific date you can do it (for example your images are in /var/www/html/web/public)

```php
<?php
$path = "/var/www/html/web/public/";
foreach (glob($path . $userId . "_" . $date" . "*") as $filename) {
    echo "your file name is : " . $filename . "\n";
}
?>
```

I hope my solution solves your problem